# How to set a specific order of DataTable?

Tags: vb.net

I populate a DataTable by a query, this query take all table name available in my database. Now what I want to do is order this table name to a specific index, for example this is the table returned:

```
appointments
planning
resources
service_categories
services
services_providers
settings
user_settings
users
```

what I'm trying to do is set this order:

```
appointments
planning
resources
service_categories
services
settings
users
user_settings
services_providers
```

**query**

```
query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                        WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='"& My.Settings.Dbname & "' "
```

I want order in this specific format the item of the `DataTable` 'cause in the next time I iterating through this object and I want have a precision iteration order of table name. How I can achieve this?

Comment: Please show the query you are using..is that order based on anything in particular?

Comment: That's an un-ordered set.  In order to sort, you have to have some value by which to sort.  Whichever column in the table defines your ordering, order by that column.

Comment: If I recall from past questions you are polling the schema to get the table names.  If you want them in a particular order create a new table such as `{tblName, SortOrder}` that will give you control over the order

Comment: You need to simply add " ORDER BY TABLE_NAME" to your query

Comment: Why? Table name order by alphabet, I want set a custom order

Comment: then create a new table where you can specify that custom order

Comment: @Plutonix uhm could you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, it's kind of a dirty way but it works on my end. There's other way's as well that were mention up above...

```
 SELECT TABLE_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = "DBNAME"
 ORDER BY 
  CASE TABLE_NAME
    WHEN 'appointments' THEN 1
    WHEN 'planning' THEN 2
    WHEN 'resources' THEN 3
    WHEN 'service_categories' THEN 4
    WHEN 'services' THEN 5
    WHEN 'settings' THEN 6
    WHEN 'users' THEN 7
    WHEN 'user_settings' THEN 8
    WHEN 'services_providers' THEN 9
 END
```

**Here is a string representation of this**

```
 "SELECT TABLE_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '" & My.Settings.Dbname & "'
 ORDER BY 
  CASE TABLE_NAME
    WHEN 'appointments' THEN 1
    WHEN 'planning' THEN 2
    WHEN 'resources' THEN 3
    WHEN 'service_categories' THEN 4
    WHEN 'services' THEN 5
    WHEN 'settings' THEN 6
    WHEN 'users' THEN 7
    WHEN 'user_settings' THEN 8
    WHEN 'services_providers' THEN 9
 END "
```

Comment: Yes unless you have a stored procedure?

Comment: I mean I should insert also the "then 1" after the tables name?